# Jenkins removing queued and running build on restart

Tags: api, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a Jenkins instance to which I am sending build request programmatically through API. My server gets restarted once in a day.

I have observed that when Jenkins server gets restarted, Jenkins is not keeping any track of queued Jobs and running jobs. We looses those jobs to be triggered.

Also I wanted to monitor programmatically if the queued build was actually executed or not. But when we restart the Jenkins, queue ids gets started from one.

Is there any way [any plugin] available that persistent the queued build and continue executing after restart in the same order as they were queued ?
Also want to continue queue numbed at which it was there before restart.

Comment: Depending on how you perform the Jenkins restart, accessing a "safe restart" through `http://your_jenkins_url/safeRestart` should only restart when there is no more jobs running.

Answer (score 0):

According to **[this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-6804)** and **[this](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Persistent+Build+Queue+Plugin)**, `/safeRestart` should be enough for what you need.

Or you can use **[Naginator](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Naginator+Plugin)** plugin to restart failed (due to Jenkins going down) builds

Comment: Thanks! /safeRestart is restarting Jenkins after completing running job, but still we are not able to recover queued jobs. Also this is for restarting Jenkins manually but in may case server itself gets restarted by scheduled

Comment: Try running https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Persistent+Build+Queue+Plugin, maybe it will actually do what you need.